# How to path-integrate over the half-line?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, path-integral, perturbation-theory, non-perturbative

Consider the path-integral over a scalar field $\varphi$:
$$
Z=\int_{\mathcal S}\ \mathrm e^{iS[\varphi]}\mathrm d\varphi
$$
where $\mathcal S$ is some function space (say, Schwartz or its dual).

How can we implement the condition $\varphi\ge0$? what effect does this restriction have, both at the perturbative level and at the non-perturbative level?

Note that this is not merely an "out of curiosity" question. The situation above occurs in practice (in its simplest manifestation, in the Higgs mechanism where we decompose $H(x)=\rho(x)\ \mathrm e^{i\sigma(x)}$; here the integral over $\rho$ is only over the half-line $\rho\ge0$).

Comment: Could you not stick a functional delta function or Heaviside step function in the integral. I have seen something similar done for path integrals on manifolds in  Statistical physics.

Comment: @Quantumspaghettification a delta function would select $\varphi\equiv0$, so I don't think that would work. A Heaviside, on the other hand, does select $\varphi\ge0$, so that's good. I'm not sure how to turn $\Theta(\varphi)$ into something manageable though. In any case, it's food for thought, so thanks!

Comment: Again going from what I know from statistical physics - you could write the Heaviside in terms of its integral representation which I assume  can be generalized to the functional case.

Comment: In perturbation theory, one usually works in the case where $\langle\rho\rangle\neq 0$ (say, in the ordered/non-vanishing vev phase), and expands $\rho=\langle\rho\rangle+\delta \rho$. Then the integral over $\delta \rho$ is not restricted (which is usually fine).

Comment: @Adam sure, in the simple case where the SSB process is triggered by a single scalar field, you are right. But in some cases, where you have several scalar fields, only some components acquire a non-zero vev. The rest do not, in which case the fluctuations in the corresponding direction are restricted to be positive.

Comment: When not in the ordered phase, one does usually not use this amplitude phase formulation, exactly because it is not easy to take care of the constraint. Note that you can also use a mixed formulation, depending on the component, in principle (I don't know if this is done in practice though).

Comment: Other ideas are to write $\rho$ as, say, $\rho= \phi^2$ or $\rho=e^{\phi}$, where $\phi\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: How about doing it by hand from the limit definition of the integral, if that is possible?

Answer (score 3):

For a free particle on the half line, the requirement that the Hamiltonian:

$$H = \frac{p^2}{2m}$$

is self adjoint

$$ (\psi ,H \phi) =  (H\psi , \phi) = \phi(0) \frac{d\psi}{dx}(0)-\psi(0) \frac{d\phi}{dx}(0)$$

(this condition means that there is no probability current crossing $x=0$), leads to a family of self adjoint extensions characterized by  the boundary conditions:

$$\psi(0) = \gamma  \frac{d\psi}{dx}(0)$$

The propagator of the general solution of the Schrodinger equation with this boundary condition is given by:

$$G(x_1, x_2) = G_0(x_2-x_1)+G_0(x_2+x_1) - 2 \gamma \int_0^{\infty}d\lambda e^{-\gamma \lambda} G_0(x_2+x_1+\lambda)$$

($G_0$ is the free unconstrained propagator; Please, see [Gamboa](https://cds.cern.ch/record/297514/files/9602158.pdf))

Both [Clark,Menikoff, and Sharp](http://inspirehep.net/record/9758?ln=en)  and  [Fahri and Gutmann](http://inspirehep.net/record/282761?ln=en)

showed that this propagator can be obtained from a path integral quantization of the free action with a delta potential at the origin for paths extending from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$.

$$L = \frac{m \dot{x}^2}{2} + \gamma \delta(x)$$

However, this is not the unique way to quantize the motion on the half line:

[Isham](http://inspirehep.net/record/192894/) , defined a quantization scheme based on the canonical transformation:

$$(x, p) \rightarrow (e^x, e^{-x}p)$$

Another quantization scheme is based on the quatization of $\mathbb{R}^+$ as a quotient space:Please see [Tanimura](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0006150v3)

$$\mathbb{R}^+ = \mathbb{R}^2/SO(2),$$

This method leads to another family of Hamiltonians:

I am not aware of any path integral formulation of the last two methods. Clearly, the last method leads to inequivalent quantizations with respect to the first one. I am quite confident that both methods can be merged to a unified method including both families of quatizations.