# Is it possible to use the Faddeev-Popov trick for discrete gauge symmetries?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory, path-integral

I was thinking of [this previous question of mine](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/396098/84967), where I was trying to implement a path-integral over the half-line:
$$
Z=\int_{\varphi\ge0}\ \mathrm e^{iS[\varphi]}\mathrm d\varphi\tag1
$$

It seems to me that a possible approach is to integrate over all $\varphi$, but to regard the configurations $\varphi$ and $-\varphi$ as physically equivalent. In other words, we take the $\mathrm d\varphi$ to be unconstrained, but we introduce the gauge equivalence $\varphi\to-\varphi$; the orbits are of the form $\{\pm\varphi\}$, and a representative of each orbit is, for example, $+\varphi$. Integrating over one representative for each orbit brings us back to $(1)$.

Instead of eliminating the gauge redundancy explicitly (which would lead to the integral I don't know how to evaluate, $(1)$), we leave the gauge symmetry as is, but treat the resulting path-integral using the standard methods of gauge-theory. The problem is that I don't know how to implement the Faddeev-Popov trick for $\mathbb Z_2$-valued gauge fields or, more generally, fields over a discrete group.

Has this problem been analysed? (How) Can we implement the Faddeev-Popov trick for system with discrete gauge symmetries?

Comment: Sorry, I am lost, why do you think that Faddeev-Popov eliminates a redundancy, in particular a scalar field?

Comment: @marmot It doesn't eliminate the scalar field, it eliminates the redundancy in $\varphi\sim-\varphi$. Just like in standard gauge theory, where the redundancy is $\phi(x)\sim \mathrm e^{i\lambda(x)}\phi(x)$ (in the case of $\mathrm U(1)$, with $\phi(x)$ complex).

Comment: This is completely new to me. As far as I know, the Faddeev-Popov ghosts exist already in a pure gauge theory, and are used to fix a gauge, i.e. to make the Klein-Gordon operator for gauge fields invertible. Why do you think they eliminate the phase of the scalar field? What if you do not gauge the theory?

Comment: @marmot I'm sure there is a misunderstanding here, because what I'm saying is basic gauge theory. You have a redundancy (in the continuous case, $\phi(x)$ and $\mathrm e^{i\lambda(x)}\phi(x)$ are gauge equivalent; in my case $\varphi(x)$ and $-\varphi(x)$ are), and you fix the redundancy by picking one representative for each gauge orbit. The representative is selected by some a priori arbitrary gauge fixing condition (in the continuous case, e.g., $\mathrm{im}(\phi(x))\equiv 0$, the unitary gauge, in my case $\varphi\ge0$). Nothing new here, except we are dealing with a *discrete* redundancy.

Comment: @marmot To make this more obvious, the continuous case is usually called $\mathrm U(1)$, and what I'm trying to understand is the $\mathrm O(1)=\mathbb Z_2$ case. They are formally the exact same problem, except that in the first case the group is continuous, and in the second case discrete. Everything else is identical. My problem is that implementing standard FP is not straightforward for discrete groups, and I would like to understand how it works.

Comment: Well, if you are sure about this, why don't you just see what happens if you get the discrete gauge symmetry in the good old-fashioned way, namely by breaking a U(1) symmetry by giving a scalar $\Phi$ of charge 2 a VEV and look at a downstairs theory with a scalar $\phi$ that had charge 1 under the U(1). It is straightforward to see that the Faddeev-Popov ghosts do nothing of the sort you have in mind (but they also did not in the upstairs theory).

Comment: Ah, one more thing, when you are talking about discrete gauge symmetries, you are taking them to be those of [arXiv:1710.01791](http://arxiv.org/abs/arXiv:1710.01791), right?

Comment: Discrete symmetries are not at all like continuous symmetries. There's a world of difference, even formally.

Comment: @MoziburUllah You are being overly categorical there. In some sense, continuous symmetries and discrete symmetries are identical, in some sense they are very different. It is simply not true that there is a world difference. Depending on the point of view you take, they have nothing to do with each other or they are the exact same thing. In this case, I was comparing them only as far as redundancy is concerned.

Comment: Agreed, I misunderstood your question on the first read. I'll delete my answer. Can you clarify, do you hope to recover the original path integral from the integrals over the whole domain of $\varphi$ *and* over whatever auxiliary fields you happen to introduce?

Comment: @SolenodonParadoxus Exactly, I expect one must introduce a $\mathbb Z_2$-valued gauge field, with its corresponding action. Presumably, $\mathbb Z_2$-valued ghost fields too. I have no idea if that is possible/useful, or one must change the paradigm completely. My hope is that one can formulate the discrete theory as close as possible to the continuous one, but I haven't been able to do it myself, and google is not helping either...

Comment: I thought $\mathbb{Z}_2$ gauge theory was only well-defined on a lattice, or in context of some background independent theory like LQG. Doesn’t it associate elements of $\mathbb{Z}_2$ to curves? Isn’t that construction fundamentally flawed because of nonseparability? How would you write down the action for such a gauge theory in continuum? Or are you considering the lattice theory from the start?

Comment: @SolenodonParadoxus No, you do not need a lattice to define a discrete gauge symmetry. ["What it means to call a $\mathbb{Z}_n$ symmetry a gauge symmetry is that when one goes around a loop in
spacetime, one might come back to the original state rotated by a symmetry element. "](http://arxiv.org/abs/arXiv:1710.01791).

Comment: @marmot I said that you need a lattice to define the action functional for such a symmetry, not the symmetry itself. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @SolenodonParadoxus Well, I guess this might be debatable. You seem to want to use the action in order to describe the QFT with the path integral. In this case I do think you need a lattice. But this is irrespective of the symmetries you are using. Sorry if I misread your statement "I thought $\mathbb{Z}_2$ gauge theory was only well-defined on a lattice..." then.

Comment: @marmot  yeah, I see what you mean. The original question was about path integrals, so I’m not sure what OP even expects to show up in the auxiliary action.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no. This has, however, nothing to do with the symmetry being discrete. Rather, it is simply the statement that Faddee-Popov ghosts never eliminate a redundancy of charged "matter" fields.

(There seems also to be some confusion on what gauge fixing does and what the ghosts do. From some text books one could get the impression that one has to eliminate the gauge redundancy in order to define the path integral. This is, however, incorrect. The thing that goes wrong on the gauge fields is that the Klein-Gordon operator has a nontrivial kernel and is hence not invertible. This is because if you apply a gauge transformation on a configuration in the kernel you get "another" configuration in the kernel. This is different from the situation of the matter fields, where the corresponding Klein-Gordon or Dirac operators have covariant derivatives in such that the above problem does not arise. What the gauge fixing and ghosts do for you is to make the Klein-Gordon operator for the gauge fields invertible on the set of the restricted gauge field configurations. That's why you get the gauge fixing parameter in the gauge field propagators only. That's it. They do not kill off phases of the matter fields in any way.)

**Literature on Yang-Mills ghosts**: I did not find any fully self-contained and clear treatment of these issues in freely available pdf files but something close to it in [Timo Weigand notes](http://www.thphys.uni-heidelberg.de/~weigand/QFT2-14/SkriptQFT2.pdf). However, the discussion in Pokorski's book on "Gauge Field Theories" is IMHO clearer, yet not publicly available. Unfortunately, the otherwise great notes by Srednicki are not 100% helpful at this point.

Comment: Please explain. If you consider Yang-Mills with charges matter, the redundancy is “spread” across gauge fields and matter, because both participate in gauge transformations. Seems to me that it contradicts your last sentence.

Comment: @SolenodonParadoxus I don't think so. Please have a look at the book by Pokorski on what gauge fixing does and what the ghosts do.

Comment: Also as a counter example consider superstring’s ghost system (whatever they call it) where there’s bosonic and fermionic ghosts canceling respectively fermionic and bosonic modes.

Comment: that’s not a fair argument. Either point out where  I am mistaken, or at least give a reference to the exact paragraph (and if possible, a pdf link).

Comment: @SolenodonParadoxus I added a longer explanation on what the ghosts do and on what they don't. A very clear discussion can be found for instance in Pokorski's book on "Gauge Field Theories" (Cambridge Monographs on Mathematical Physics), for which I do not have a pdf for obvious reasons. Of course, these statements can be found in other text books as well, I just don't remember which ones.

Comment: @marmot I'm not sure "matter" vs. "gauge" is a meaningful dichotomy. Would you call a Rarita-Schwinger field matter or gauge? Its kinetic term has a non-trivial kernel too, but it is fermionic. Its FP ghosts are scalars (bosonic).

Comment: It seems to me that this answer desperately lacks generality. I don't believe that OP necessarily considers Yang-Mills interactions, actually, I think OP has something completely different in mind. Like a discrete symmetry of the scalar field, which can be gauge-fixed by something resembling Faddeev-Popov. And Faddeev-Popov definitely *can* be applied to other symmetries rather than Yang-Mills coupled to scalars/fermions, one example is given by the superstring ghost system. I definitely expect the answer to the question to be "no", but I don't find your explanation satisfactory, sorry.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform I didn't know you were thinking about gravity here but I would call a gravitino a gravitino if it is a gravitino of supergravity. And yes, "gauge fixing" in gravity is more tricky but conceptually not different from what I wrote above.

Comment: @SolenodonParadoxus Well, we seem to agree in the conclusion but again I disagree with you in what gauge fixing does. BTW, the OP's setup *can* be obtained by spontaneously break a U(1) gauge symmetry down to a $\mathbb{Z}_2$, and there one can just see what the ghosts do: nothing.